# SQL Metadata Search via SharePoint

Tags: sql, performance, sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to search the metadata of SQL Databases (example: extended properties) via SharePoint? maybe using FAST?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Business Connectivity Services (BCS) to define the structure of your remote sql database and then you can crawl it with search.  An intro to this is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taj/archive/2010/08/24/searching-external-systems-using-sharepoint-2010-business-connectivity-services-bcs-within-throttling-limits.aspx